# Ярлыки сайтов как приложения

Tags: javascript, android, html, мобильные-приложения

На Андроиде некоторые сайты, при использовании опции "Добавить на главный экран" в хроме, сохраняются как приложения. Они открываются без использования хрома. Непонятно: то ли гугловским браузером, то ли как открываются. И возможен просмотр оффлайн. А некоторые просто открываются, как ярлыки и открываются только в онлайн в хроме. Как такие сайты (как приложения) делаются? Манифестный файл или в мета где то что то прописать надо?

Comment: Я сам не знаю, но читал что то, что это SPA приложения

Answer (score 1):

Такие сайты, работающие оффлайн называют Progressive Web Application PWA. Все верно, такое приложение - экземпляр вкладки браузера со специально настроенными манифестом, ServiceWorker (изолированный поток исполнения) и хранилищами данных. Как отправную точку для ознакомления можно использовать эту статью https://m.habr.com/ru/post/418923/. Но, ИМХО, серьезное нативное приложение PWA заменить не сможет.

Comment: заменить не сможет(c) например?